# If $T$ is a projection, then $V = R_T \oplus N_T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, $T$ a linear operator on $V$, $N_T$ the nullspace of $T$, $R_T$ the range of $T$. I am trying to prove the following statement. If $T$ is a projection, then $V = N_T \oplus R_T$.

By definition of a projection, $T^2 = T$. It follows that  $x \in R_T$ iff $Tx = x$. So now, I think it should be straightforward to show that if  $x \notin R_T$ then $Tx = 0$, but I cannot seem to think of the argument. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that $V=R_T+N_T$ and that $R_T\cap N_T=0$.

For the latter assume $x\in R_T\cap N_T$. So $x=Ty$ for some $y\in V$ and $Tx=0$. But then $0=Tx=TTy=Ty=x$ as desired.

Now let $x\in V$ be arbitrary. Let $a=Tx$, $b=x-a$. Clearly, $a\in R_T$. Also, $Tb=Tx-Ta=Tx-TTx=Tx-Tx=0$, so $b\in N_T$. As $x=a+b$ we see that $V=R_T+N_T$.

---

Note that in general we do *not* have $Tx=0$ for all $x\notin R_T$.